# Function for changing a tile to multiple tiles Ex: 5x7

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in unity (C#) and I am placing tiles on my tile map and then separating them. Once they are separated I need to turn them into "rooms" or squares. How can I do this starting from the middle tile (origin/the only tile)

Comment: Can you add some sample images? You have to do these operations in the editor, right? Not in runtime with code?

Comment: @iFralex I need to do this with code, I can set them at the coordinates I just need help with the algorithm. Originally I thought to subtract one to the size and divide like so:

5x5 = 2 down, 2 up, 2 right, 2 left

however, this does not work with not perfect numbers, like 5x7

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I need more information to fully understand your problem and help you. how do you have to arrange the tiles? Why from 5x5 do you say 2 up, 2 down, 2 right and 2 left? Hope to help you out with this information :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @iFralex I say 2 up 2 down because, 5-1/2, however this doesn't work with weird numbers. I am using Unity's SetTile function that takes in a Vector3Int so I can add to the vectors as I need for the math.

Comment: Lets say I start with this square, the one in red. 

https://i.imgur.com/EPpeOtD.png

I need to make my desired square size with only adding and subtracting vector values to place a new vector there. If I added a 1 to my X it may be like this: https://i.imgur.com/BHjvlNZ.png

So now I have two tiles, and effectively a 2x1, if I subtract an X I may have this:

https://i.imgur.com/FD2cZZa.png

Three tiles now. Knowing this how can I create my desired sizes with an function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!
with the function below you can have what you ask for.
In practice, it builds line by line, starting from the bottom.
When he got the vector of a cell, he adds 0.5f or 1 (depending on whether it's even or odd) to each coordinate, and subtracts half of the "size" vector.
This way the center will always be on (0, 0) and the other vectors will be as in the example you did.

**Script:**

```
public void Calculate(Vector2 size)
{
    List<Vector2> results = new List<Vector2>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size.y; i++)
        for (int o = 0; o < size.x; o++)
            results.Add(new Vector2(o, i) + (new Vector2(size.x % 2 != 0 ? .5f : 1, size.y % 2 != 0 ? .5f : 1) - (size / 2)));
    string st = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
        st += "\n" + results[i].ToString();
    print(st);
}

void Start()
{
    Calculate(new Vector2(5, 7));
}
```

**Output for Calculate(new Vector2(5, 7)), as the question title:**
(-2.00, -3.00)
(-1.00, -3.00)
(0.00, -3.00)
(1.00, -3.00)
(2.00, -3.00)
(-2.00, -2.00)
(-1.00, -2.00)
(0.00, -2.00)
(1.00, -2.00)
(2.00, -2.00)
(-2.00, -1.00)
(-1.00, -1.00)
(0.00, -1.00)
(1.00, -1.00)
(2.00, -1.00)
(-2.00, 0.00)
(-1.00, 0.00)
(0.00, 0.00)
(1.00, 0.00)
(2.00, 0.00)
(-2.00, 1.00)
(-1.00, 1.00)
(0.00, 1.00)
(1.00, 1.00)
(2.00, 1.00)
(-2.00, 2.00)
(-1.00, 2.00)
(0.00, 2.00)
(1.00, 2.00)
(2.00, 2.00)
(-2.00, 3.00)
(-1.00, 3.00)
(0.00, 3.00)
(1.00, 3.00)
(2.00, 3.00)